# Identifying XLH 883 Screw leaking oil

Tags: motorcycle, oil-leak, screw

Need help identifying screw next to kickstand for 1990 883 xlh Harley Sportster. Is currently leaking oil.

[image: Screw in question]

Comment: Please take another photograph using something other than a potato.

Comment: Are you asking how to identify the screw in hopes of getting a replacement screw, or are you asking what the purpose of the "screw" is?

Answer (score -1):

Best way to find out where that is coming from is to run the bike until it's hot, park it out in the sun and wait for it to start leaking. Then you'll get a good idea of where the leak is coming from.

Comment: A modified, enhanced version of this method uses an inexpensive flourescing dye and UV flashlight. I have this one (s://www.amazon.com/FJC-4972-Fluorescent-Leak-Detection/), but there are options available for $10-$20 USD.